# how to enable https from java application

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

I am using core java for my rest service. Based on my requirement I cannot use spring boot for rest endpoint.
I achieved implementing http endpoint from core java.

But I cannot enable HTTPS via core java application.

I have .p12 file with me. Is there any way to enable HTTPS for Core java application ?

Below is my code

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
            server.createContext("/endpoint", new CustomHttpHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**CustomHttpHandler**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

public class CustomHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange res) throws IOException {

        String response = "Response from server";
        res.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream outputStream = res.getResponseBody();
        outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }

}
```